# preg_match() giving Unknown modifier '$'

Tags: php, preg-match, modifier

I've got the following code

```
function redireectIfNeeded(){
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if(preg_match("/\.php/$", $url))
    header("Location: ".preg_replace("/\.php/",$url));
}
```

Which is giving me the following error.

```
[24-Jul-2012 19:14:18] PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '$' in ../dbc.php on line 223
```

I know I need a delimiter somewhere, but nothing I've tried is working. Can anyone let me know what I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set $ before /

```
if(preg_match("/\.php$/", $url))
    header("Location: ".preg_replace("/\.php/",$url));
}
```

After delimiter you can use modificator (s, m or i)